# SuppressWarnings "all" complaint from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dead-code, suppress-warnings

What is wrong with the `SuppressWarnings` annotation above the `if` statement?  Eclipse with Sun JDK 6 provides two syntax error descriptions, both unhelpful and hard to understand, shown in comments.

```
class TestDeadCode
{
    //@SuppressWarnings("all")
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("all")  // syntax errors: insert enum body, insert enum id
        if ((Constants.flag0) && (Constants.flag1))
            System.out.println("hello\n");      
    }
}

interface Constants
{
    boolean flag0 = false;
    boolean flag1 = false;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only classes, methods, variable declarations, parameters and packages may be annotated. Therefore, you cannot use SuppressWarnings("all") on an if statement.

To fix this issue, you can simply do the following.

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
boolean flag = Constants.flag0 && Constants.flag1;
if (flag) {
    System.out.println("hello\n");
}
```

There is no SuppressWarnings("Dead code") as of yet.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html
http://pmd.sourceforge.net/suppressing.html

Comment: bah, just beat me to the post!

Comment: Additionally, you can tell eclipse to ignore the dead code warning.
Windows > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings
In the "Potential programming problems" section towards the bottom is "Dead Code"